# Gramática Yacc - PLY

Tags: python, yacc

El problema con el que cuento es que no se cual es el  error que genera mi código hecho en PLY en el apartado YACC. He estado checando en la mayoria de las paginas del creador y aun no logro ver realmente si fue mi error de construcción del lexicografico o el semantico o los dos. Les agradezco mucho por su atencion espero que tengan alguna respuesta.

Error:

```
Stack  : PROGRAM LLAVEI INT . LexToken(ID,'x',1,14)
ERROR: Error  : PROGRAM LLAVEI INT . LexToken(ID,'x',1,14)
Syntax error at token ID
```

Llevo revisando tanto mi apartado Lexicográfico tanto como el Semántico y no logro percibir que lo genera según yo esta bien como construir el ID.

Les dejo el código del lex y yacc.

LEX:

```
import ply.lex as lex
tokens=['DIGITO','IDEN','SUMA','RESTA','MULTIPLICAR','DIVISION','MENORQ','MENORI','MAYORQ','MAYORI','IGUALI','DIFERENTEI','IGUAL','PUNTOC','COMA','PARENTI','PARENTD','LLAVEI','LLAVED']
reserved= {
   'program' : 'PROGRAM',
   'if' : 'IF',
   'else' : 'ELSE',
   'fi' : 'FI',
   'do' : 'DO',
   'until' : 'UNTIL',
   'while' : 'WHILE',
   'read' : 'READ',
   'write' : 'WRITE',
   'float' : 'FLOAT',
   'int' : 'INT',
   'bool' : 'BOOL',
   'not' : 'NOT',
   'and' : 'AND',
   'or' : 'OR',
   'then' : 'THEN',
   'true' : 'TRUE',
   'false' : 'FALSE'
}
tokens += reserved.values()

#EXPRESIONES REGULARES

t_SUMA = r'\+'
t_RESTA = r'-'
t_MULTIPLICAR = r'\*'
t_DIVISION = r'/'
t_GORRITO = r'\^'
t_MENORQ = r'\<'
t_MENORI = r'\<\='
t_MAYORQ = r'\>'
t_MAYORI = r'\>\='
t_IGUALI = r'\=\='
t_DIFERENTEI = r'\!\='
t_IGUAL = r'\='
t_PUNTOC = r'\;'
t_COMA = r'\,'
t_PARENTI = r'\('
t_PARENTD = r'\)'
t_LLAVEI = r'\{'
t_LLAVED = r'\}'
t_IDEN = r'[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'

def t_ID(t):
#    r'[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+'
#    r'\w+(_\d\w)*'
#     
   r'[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
   t.type = reserved.get(t.value,'ID')    # Check for reserved words
   return t

def t_DECIM(t):
   r'\d+'
   t.value = int(t.value)    
   return t

def t_REAL(t):
   r'\d+.d+'
   return t

def t_newline(t): # SALTO DE LINEA
   r'\n+'
   t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)

def t_error(t): # ERRORES
   print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
   t.lexer.skip(1)

t_ignore  = ' \t' #IGNORAR ESPACIO Y TABULADOS

#CONSTRUIMOS EL LEXICOGRAFICO
lexer = lex.lex(optimize=1,lextab="footab")
```

YACC:

```
from alexico import tokens,lexer #importaremos el lexico y los tokens

resultado_gramatica=""
nombres=[] #ALMACENAREMOS LAS VARIABLES QUE SE VAYAN A USAR
precedence = ( #ORGANIZAMOS DE LA JERARQUIA DE OP. LOGICOS
   ('right','IGUAL'),
   ('right','IGUALI'),
   ('left','MAYORQ','MENORQ'),
   ('left','SUMA','RESTA'),
   ('left','MULTIPLICAR','DIVISION'),
   ('left','PARENTI','PARENTD'),
   ('left','LLAVEI','LLAVED')
   )

def p_programa(p):
   '''programa : PROGRAM LLAVEI lista_declaracion lista_sentencias LLAVED'''
   p[0] = [p[3]] + [p[4]]

# INICIAMOS CON TODA LA PARTE DE        LISTA-DECLARACION
def p_lista_declaracion(p):
   'lista_declaracion : lista_declaracion declaracion'
   p[1].append(p[2])
   p[0]=p[1]

def p_lista_declaracion_declaracion(p):
   '''lista_declaracion : declaracion 
                       | empty'''
   p[0]=p[1]

def p_declaracion(p):
   '''declaracion : tipo lista_id PUNTOC'''
   p[0] = p[1] + [p[2]]

def p_tipo(p):
   ''' tipo : INT 
           | FLOAT
           | BOOL'''
   #nombres[p[0]] = p[1]
   p[0]=p[1]

def p_lista_id(p):
   '''lista_id : IDEN 
               | COMA IDEN'''
   if p[1] != ',':
       #nombres[p[0]] = p[1]
       p[0]=p[1]
   else:
       p[0]=p[2]
       #nombres[p[0]] = p[2]


# INICIAMOS CON TODA LA PARTE DE        LISTA-SENTENCIAS
def p_lista_sentencias(p):
   'lista_sentencias : lista_sentencias sentencias'
   p[1].append(p[2])
   p[0]=p[1]

def p_lista_sentencias(p):
   '''lista_sentencias : sentencia
                       | empty
   '''
   p[0] = p[1]

def p_sentencia(p):
   '''sentencia : seleccion
               | iteracion
               | repeticion
               | sent_read
               | sent_write
               | bloque
               | asignacion'''
   p[0]=p[1]

def p_seleccion(p):
   ''' seleccion : IF PARENTI b_expresion PARENTD THEN bloque FI
                   |  IF PARENTI b_expresion PARENTD THEN bloque ELSE bloque FI'''
   if p[7] != 'else':
       if(p[3]):
           p[0]=p[6]
   else:
       if(p[3]):
           p[0]=p[6]
       else:
           p[0]=p[8]

def p_iteracion(p):
   '''iteracion : WHILE PARENTI b_expresion PARENTD bloque'''
   p[0] = p[3] + [p[5]]

def p_repeticion(p):
   '''repeticion : DO bloque UNTIL PARENTI b_expresion PARENTD PUNTOC'''
   p[0] = [p[2]] + p[5]
   #queda pendiente

def p_sent_read(p):
   '''sent_read : READ IDEN PUNTOC'''
   p[0] = p[2]

def p_sent_write(p):
   '''sent_write : WRITE b_expresion PUNTOC'''
   p[0] = p[2]

def p_bloque(p):
   '''bloque : PARENTI lista_sentencias PARENTD 
               | empty'''
   p[0] = p[2]

def p_asignacion(p):
   '''asignacion : IDEN IGUAL b_expresion PUNTOC'''
   p[0] = p[3]

def p_b_expresion(p):
   '''b_expresion : b_term 
                   | OR b_term
   '''
   if p[1] != 'or':
       p[0] = p[1]
   else:
       p[0] = p[2]

def p_b_term(p):
   '''b_term : not_factor
               | AND not_factor
   '''
   if p[1] != 'and':
       p[0] = p[1]
   else:
       p[0] = p[2]

def p_not_factor(p):
   'not_factor : NOT b_factor'
   p[0] = p[1]

def p_b_factor(p):
   '''b_factor : TRUE 
               | FALSE 
               | relacion '''
   p[0]=p[1]

def p_relacion(p):
   '''relacion : expresion relOp expresion '''
   p[0] = [p[1]] + [p[3]]

def p_relOp(p):
   '''relOp : MENORI
               | MENORQ
               | MAYORQ
               | MAYORI
               | IGUALI
               | DIFERENTEI '''
   p[0] = p[1]

def p_expresion(p):
   '''expresion : termino sumaOp'''
   p[0]= p[1]

def p_sumaOp(p):
   '''sumaOp : SUMA
               | RESTA'''
   p[0] = p[1]

def p_termino(p):
   '''termino : signoFactor multOp signoFactor
   '''
   p[0] = p[1],p[3]

def p_multOp(p):
   '''multOp : MULTIPLICAR
               | DIVISION'''
   p[0] = p[1]

def p_signoFactor(p):
   'signoFactor : sumaOp factor'
   p[0] = p[2]

def p_factor(p):
   '''factor : PARENTI b_expresion PARENTD
               | DIGITO
               | IDEN '''
   if p[1] == '(':
       p[0] = p[2]
   else:
       p[0] = p[1]

def p_empty(p):
    'empty :'
    pass

#def p_error(p):
#    if p:
#         print("Syntax error at token", p.type)
#         # Just discard the token and tell the parser it's okay.
#         yacc.yacc().errok()
#    else:
#         print("Syntax error at EOF")

def p_error(p):    
   if p:
       print("Syntax error at token", p.type)
       # Just discard the token and tell the parser it's okay.
       yacc.yacc().errok() 
   else: print("Syntax error at EOF")
   
#main
yacc.yacc(optimize=1)
yacc.yacc().defaulted_states = {}

while True:
  try:
      s = "program { int x; }" #Aqui leo la cadena a evaluar
  except EOFError:
      break
  if not s: continue
  result = yacc.yacc().parse(s,tracking=True,debug=True)
  print(result)
```

Esta es la gramática que utilice:

```
programa ::= program ”{” lista-declaración lista-sentencias ”}”
lista-declaración ::= { declaración }
declaración ::= tipo lista-id ”;”
tipo ::= int | float | bool
lista-id ::= id { ”,” id }
lista-sentencias ::= { sentencias }
sentencia ::= selección | iteración | repetición | sent-read |
sent-write | bloque | asignación
selección ::= if ”(” b-expresión ”)” then bloque [ else bloque ] fi
iteración ::= while ”(” b-expresión ”)” bloque
repetición ::= do bloque until ”(” b-expresión ”)” ”;”
sent-read ::= read id ”;”
sent-write ::= write b-expresión ”;”
bloque ::= ”{” lista-sentencia ”}”
asignación ::= id ”=” b-expresión ”;”
b-expresión ::= b-term { OR b-term }
b-term ::= not-factor { AND not-factor }
not-factor ::= [NOT] b-factor
b-factor ::= (true|false) | relación
relación ::= expresión [ relOp expresión ]
relOp ::= <= | < | > | >= | == | !=
expresión → termino { sumaOp termino }
suma-op → + | -
termino → signoFactor { multOp signoFactor }
mult-op → * | /
signoFactor → [ sumaOp ] factor
factor → ”(” b-expresión ”)” | numero | id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu gramática dice (en `p_lista_id`):

```
lista_id : IDEN
```

Sin embargo, se puede ver que el analizador léxico producía el token `ID`:

```
Error  : PROGRAM LLAVEI INT . LexToken(ID,'x',1,14)
```

Como el analizador sintáctico está esperando `IDEN` y lo que recibe es `ID`, no lo acepta.

En tu apartado lexicografíco, tienes dos patrones iguales, uno un variable y otro una función:

```py
t_IDEN = r'[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'

def t_ID(t):   
   r'[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
```

Obviamente, solo uno podría ser aceptado. El analizador léxico de Ply, a diferencia de muchos otros, simplemente devuelve el primer patrón que coincide, así que el orden de patrones es sumamente importante. Esta descrito en la documentación, pero la resumen es que primero intenta las funciones, en la orden que aparecen en el apartado, y después los patrones en variables, de lo más largo hacia lo mas corto. Así que elige la función en lugar del variable, por lo que el token es `ID`.

Me parece que `t_IDEN` fue una equivocación. Debería eliminarlo, cambiar `IDEN` por `ID` en todas las reglas sintácticas, y también sacarlo de la lista de tokens.

Por otro lado, hay una ambigüedad en:

```py
def p_lista_declaracion_declaracion(p):
   '''lista_declaracion : declaracion 
                       | empty'''
   p[0]=p[1]
```

Solo necesitas una de las reglas; con las dos, tienes un conflicto. Si tu intención fue que la lista de declaraciones pueda ser vacío, necesitas solo:

```py
def p_lista_declaracion_declaracion(p):
   '''lista_declaracion : empty'''
   p[0]=[]
```

Si tiene que ser por lo menos una declaración en la lista, necesitas:

```py
def p_lista_declaracion_declaracion(p):
   '''lista_declaracion : declaracion '''
   p[0]=[p[1]]
```

En cualquier caso, hay que asegurarse que el valor semántico sea un *list* de declaraciones, como he hecho arriba. En la tuya, el valor es una declaración, si el analizador opta por `lista_declaracion : declaracion`, o `None` si opta por `lista_declaracion : empty` (porque `p_empty` no asigna valor ningún a `p[0]`).